# Sitecore sxa site not showing add site and remove site option in Context menu

Tags: sxa

I have installed Sitecore 9.1 version in local system and  have installed SXA 1.8. However, I am not able to see add site option when I am trying to click on tenant site.

[image]

When I am trying to search the option for "Remove site" by clicking on SXA site under script , it is not showing anything related to it.

[image]

I have seen the upgrade option as well to cross check that SXA has installed or not.

[image]

Kindly let me know ,how I can see all the options related to Sitecore SXA ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have the following item in your modules folder:
`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Scaffolding/Content Editor/Insert Item/Site`

Also, check the Show Rule field in the above item is satisfying the conditions to insert the site

Comment: No, I don't have these folder under mentioned path.

Comment: Please try to reinstall the Sxa package

Comment: Reinstalling SXA package throwing an error , Do we need to remove existing sxa package files ? if yes then could you please let me know the locations ?

Comment: Can you please send details of the error? Also try to install the package with overwrite option.